# Could not install app on Apple Watch due to UIDeviceRequiredCapabilities

Tags: ios, xcode, watchos

I've been getting rejected by the Apple review process many times due to the following reason:

```
Guideline 2.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata

We were unable to install the app on Apple Watch. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not install on Apple Watch.

We reviewed your app on iPhone XR running 15.2.1 and on Apple Watch 6 running 8.4.1 on WiFi.
```

Below are the Info.plist found in the Archive of the project.

Companion App Info.plist
[image]

Apple Watch App Info.plist
[image]

In the companion app, I do have the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities node, but it has a value of arm64, which should be fine since that will allow it to run on the iPhone XR on the tester's device. If I remove the entire node, then Xcode archive will complain that I haven't defined any value at all.

I've tried removing some keys like LSIphoneRequired as well based on other similar answers on stackoverflow and even trying to tell the reviewer that I have tested and verified the TestFlight for myself and another friend with an Apple Watch.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

Comment: It did end up passing Apple review. But I can’t quite remember the solution, sorry. But you can find the app here https://github.com/uioporqwerty/waka-watch if that helps.

Comment: For me, I informed App Review that it was a Watch-only app, and they asked me to submit a video of the app working. Looks like App Review is unable to install watch-only apps.